# Is the inverse of the deformation gradient simply the deformation gradient of the inverse transformation?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, continuum-mechanics, calculus

If we have a continuum where the initial positions are denoted $X$ and the positions after some deformation are denoted $x$, the deformation gradient is defined:

$$ F = \frac{\partial x}{\partial X} $$

If we instead start at $x$ and undergo a deformation to $X$, we might write:

$$ F_* = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} $$

Is $F_*$ just equal to $F^{-1}$? It seems like it should be true intuitively, but I don't know how to formally demonstrate it.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic yeah, I waffled over this, but ultimately chose Physics since it seemed to have more continuum-mechanics related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(FF_*)_{ij} = \sum_k \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_k} \frac{\partial X_k}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij}\:.$$
In other words
$$FF_* =I$$
so that, since the matrices are square ones,
$$F_*F =I\:.$$
That is equivalent to saying $F_* = F^{-1}.$